# Core Data - NSManagedObject (with relationships) to JSON

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and I want to convert NSManagedObject (fetched from local database) to a JSON string. It's a simple object with relationships, as you can see above:

[image: Entities]

That's the code that I use for fetching:

```
func loadData() {
    //1
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Bill")

    //3
    do {
        let fetchedData = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Bill]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

How can I convert fetchedData into a JSON string? I'd like to use Codable but i don't know if it's supported.

Comment: You can implement Codable (Encodable should be enough?) in an extension but you need to do all the mapping manually.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how can I map "lots" relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an extension for each class and let it implement `Encodable`. Something like this for Lot

```
extension Lot: Encodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case quantity
    case expiration
    case quantity_packages
  }

  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(quantity, forKey: . quantity)
    try container.encode(expiration, forKey: . expiration)
    try container.encode(quantity_packages, forKey: . quantity_packages)
}
```

and for Bill, notice that I convert `lots` from `NSSet` to `Array`

```
extension Bill: Encodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
    case lots
  }

  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    if let array = lots?.allObjects as? [Lot] {
        try container.encode(array, forKey: .lots)
    } // else Not sure what to do here, maybe use an empty array?
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to test this properly but I hope this helps.